# C#: Drawing method used by Picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

**Background:** In a Picturebox, Bitmap images can be drawn on screen by assigning a Bitmap object to Picturebox's Image property.

**Question:**   What's the drawing method (GDI+?) used by Picturebox to paint bitmap image on screen?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by `PictureBox` you mean `System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox`, it paints with GDI+ as GDI+ is the rendering technology used by all of Windows Forms (WinForms). The GDI+ "wrapper" for WinForms comes from `System.Drawing`.

Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) on the other hand, uses DirectX to "paint". WPF does not have a PictureBox control.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted to know :).